# Could Naruto's shadow clones transport jutsu?

Tags: naruto

In Naruto's battle against Pain,

> Naruto transports his sage mode chakra through shadow clones that he got back in frog town.

Would this also mean that if Naruto makes his clone cast a jutsu, then dispell it, the jutsu would also return to the owner?

Comment: What kinds of justus do you expect to be transferred for instance?

Comment: @MadaraUchiha for an example Rasen shuriken, It is throwable so the dispell part as in Tartori's answer should not affect it

Comment: Well, maybe if he threw it at another clone (or the original) then dispelled, maybe then it would work. But if the clone simply dispels without doing anything, I think Tartori's answer is correct.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Also think tatoris answer is correct. but ill wait for a bit before accepting. see if more intresting answers pop up :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The chakra is equally divided between all the shadow clones, so when one dies or disappears, the original will get the chakra they had left back (with all their memories). It's another thing with jutsus, when he generates a Rasengan, for instance, it is used, it is there. When the shadow clone then disappears, the jutsu is released and it will disappear to.